# Php evaluate a string as variable and extract value of it

Tags: php, string, variables, evaluation

```
<?php        
     $i=2;
     $teststring='$_SESSION["REGISTERED"]["FirstName'.$i.'"]';      
     var_dump($teststring); 
     die; 
     if(isset(($teststring))){
         //do something 
     }
?>
```

In above code I want find the value of `$_SESSION["REGISTERED"]["FirstName2']` variable , I need suggestion/trick

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
$foo = $_SESSION['REGISTERED']["FirstName$i"];
```

Array keys are just strings, and they CAN be dynamically generated. There is absolutely no difference in PHP between these two:

```
$foo = array('bar' => 'baz');
$x = 'bar';

echo $foo[$x];
echo $foo['bar'];
```

both will output `baz`.

Comment: bro , I already spend a day on this but you saved my other day now , thank you very much, this is working as u said

Answer (score 0):

you don't need extra quote for FirstName:

```
$teststring=$_SESSION["REGISTERED"]["FirstName".$i];
```

will simply work.